# Bluetooth controls from Notification Center on iPad

Tags: ios, bluetooth, tethering, notifications

I find myself spending a lot of time moving through the menus to re-connect my iPad to my iPhone to tether the network.

It would be great to be able to perform this task (or at least speed it up) from the notification center.

Now that iOS 5.1.1 has been jailbroken I have SBSettings toggles working in the notification center on my iPad3 so I can *toggle* the bluetooth on and off from there, but I cannot get it to connect to my iPhone.

Even something as basic as a shortcut-icon to open up Bluetooth Settings would work. Activator has an action that does this that I can assign but curiously there doesn't seem to be a way to add such an action as an icon in notification center.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a browse through the Cydia app and I found iTether w/OnDemand and it also has a SBSetting toggle to go with it.

Now it is $5, so I am not goign to buy and try, but seeing your question it seems to solve what you want to achieve:-)

Comment: That sounds like it might do what I want... I'll post back with results when I try it out.

Comment: Hi Steven, just a heads up - without saying to much - but soon you will not have to jailbreak your device for this option:-)

Comment: I haven't gotten to the iOS6 part of the WWDC feed yet :) These are exciting times. I just applied for the iOS developer program today as well.

Comment: Enjoy it:-) Feel free to ask any questions on StackOverflow.com - they are really helpful bunch of people:-)